# How much data is needed for transfer learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, sentiment-analysis, transfer-learning

I have a pre-trained sentiment classifier on Amazon reviews and I want to use it for transfer learning to classify sentiments on a specific aspect of some products, for example how a person feels about the battery life of a phone. How much data do I have to typically provide for this type of transfer learning?

I don't expect it will be so much since the two problems are quite similar in nature, it's just the latter is more fine grained. However, it may depend on the model that's being used, let's say a network with just an LSTM and a Dense layer with sigmoid activation. How would this affect the amount of data needed?

Comment: What are your inputs? Is it a plain text in the same language?

Comment: @KarelMacek Let's say word2vec vectors trained on the same corpus